# Sorting files from directoryinfo by date in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have this code and i want to see the last record on top. i've tried some answers but didn't work out.

```
dim a = Request("a")

dim thisOne as new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(a))
dim subDirectories as DirectoryInfo() = thisOne.GetDirectories()
dim theFiles() as FileInfo = thisOne.GetFiles()


dim j = 0
%>   
<table id="RESIMLISTESIBILGISI">
    <%While j<theFiles.Length %>    
    <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="SilinecekDosya" value="<%=a%>/<%=theFiles(j).Name%>"></td>
      <td><a href="#d" onclick="DA('<%=a.replace("\", "\\")%>/<%=theFiles(j).Name%>')"><%=theFiles(j).Name%></a></td>
        <td><%=FormatNumber(theFiles(j).Length/1024 ,0)%></td>
    </tr>   
    <%
  j += 1
    end while
  %>
```

Comment: `thisOne.EnumerateFiles().OrderBy( Function (x) x.CreationTime).toArray()`  there are several Dates to choose from in FileInfo

Comment: didn't work out. getting error...

Comment: And you don't think the error message is important enough to tell us?

Comment: 'OrderBy', is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of System.IO.FileInfo)' .

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to put the files you have into a list, because lists can be sorted using custom functions. Then you create a custom function that will sort the files according to your needs. Finally you call that sorting function inside a for each loop (because I don't like whiles...)

So the comparison function :

```
Private Function SortByDate(X As FileInfo, Y As FileInfo) As Integer
    Return X.CreationTime.CompareTo(Y.CreationTime)
End Function
```

Then inside your code :

```
Dim dir As New DirectoryInfo("My\Directory\Path")
Dim fileList As List(Of FileInfo) = dir.GetFiles().ToList()
fileList.Sort(AddressOf SortByDate)

For Each F As FileInfo In fileList
    'Do some stuff
    MessageBox.Show(F.Name) 'This should display the filename
Next
```

That should do the trick...